# Google Data Studio: How Do I Multiply Two Score Cards?

Tags: google, data, google-data-studio

I am using Google Data Studio and Dashboard that has a couple of score cards on it.

Some of these score cards are affected by filters and some are not. I want to multiply these score cards together to get a value.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with calculated fields. I find them pretty useful in a variety of situations.

For further information on calculated fields and how to create them, the following page has helpful information:
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en